# Core Data : Batch Faulting while take advantage of cache

Tags: ios, core-data

In "Core Data Programming Guide"  Apple recommend a way to batch fire fault a collection of objects,  It should be implemented as below:

```
NSArray * arrayOfFaults = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1,object2,nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@", arrayOfFaults];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Foo"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
```

However using "Core Data" Instrument on iOS 6 simulator,  I found this fetch almost as same time as other fetch. In other words, it goes to disk and did not use the cache. It's unreasonable .  Since it's an " IN " clause , Core Data could use the objectID to find object in cache. There are no need to go to the disk if all of them could be found in cache.

I am pretty sure these objects in arrayOfFaults are in cache.  If I replace above code with this one, not cache miss are reported:

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in arrayOfFaults){
   [object willAccessValueForKey:nil];
}
```

So my question is : are there any way to batch fault objects while take advantage of the cache ?